# How fix redirecting with parameter have error

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

In my Laravel 5.8 app when there are no data in session I need to redirect to some default control.

I do

```php
return redirect()->route('admin.oauthAdminCallback/' . $form_action);
```

When in `routes/web.php` defined :

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVerified', 'CheckUserStatus'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {    
    Route::get('oauthAdminCallback/{form_action}', [ 'uses' => 'Admin\EventsController@oauthAdminCallback']);//->name('oauthAdminCallback');
```

But I got error :

```php
Route [admin.oauthAdminCallback/calendarActionUpdate] not defined.
```

If in first line `$form_action` has value : “calendarActionUpdate”. 
Which is correct way ?

**MODIFIED :**
I tried this way

```php
return redirect()->route('admin.oauthAdminCallback',$form_action);
```

and this way

```php
        return redirect()->route('admin.oauthAdminCallback')->with([
            'form_action'   => $form_action,
        ]);
```

But in both cases I do not have amy error but method was not called!

In my routes/web.php :

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVerified', 'CheckUserStatus'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('oauthAdminCallback', [ 'as' => 'oauthAdminCallback', 'uses' =>'Admin\EventsController@oauthAdminCallback']);
```

// The method below is not called!

```php
public function oauthAdminCallback()
{
    session_start();

    die("-1 XXZ oauthAdminCallback");
```

return redirect( is ignored and I can not understand why?

Comment: try removing middleware from route. may be one of it not fulfill condition and stop execution.

Comment: That seems good assumption to move Route from Route::group and I did it as :
Route::get('admin/oauthAdminCallback', [ 'as' => 'admin.oauthAdminCallback', 'uses' =>'Admin\EventsController@oauthAdminCallback']); 

But anyway my action oauthAdminCallback is not triggered. But if to comment 1st row at top I got error that oauthAdminCallback is not defined...

Any adea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're calling the route by its name so

try this

```
return redirect()->route('admin.oauthAdminCallback',$form_action);
```

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Comment: maybe from middleware check your middleware is returning true

Answer (score 1):

Mention your route as

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('oauthAdminCallback', [ 'as' => 'oauthAdminCallback', 'uses' => 'Admin\EventsController@oauthAdminCallback']);
});
```

And your callback as below

```
return redirect()->route('admin.oauthAdminCallback', $form_action);
```

**Tried and tested.**

Comment: If this works... there is problem with your 'isVerified', 'CheckUserStatus' middleware. It won't fulfill your condition